# nhibernate lazy loading uses implicit transaction

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, lazy-loading

This seems to be a pretty common problem: I load an NHibernate object that has a lazily loaded collection.
At some later point, I access the collection to do something.
I still have the nhibernate session open (as it's managed per view or whatever) so it does actually work but the transaction is closed so in NHprof I get 'use of implicit transactions is discouraged'.

I understand this message and since I'm using a unit of work implementation, I can fix it simply by creating a new transaction and wrapping the call to the lazy loaded collection within it.

My problem is that this doesn't feel right...
I have this great NHibernate framework that gives me nice lazy loading but I can't use it without wrapping every property access in a transaction.

I've googled this a lot, read plenty of blog posts, questions on SO, etc, but can't seem to find a complete solution.

This is what I've considered:

1. Turn off lazy loading. I think this is silly, it's like getting a full on sports car and then only ever driving it in eco mode. Eager loading everything would hurt performance and if I just had ids instead of references then why bother with Nhibernate at all?
2. Keep the transaction open longer. Transactions should not be long lived and keeping one open as long as a view is open would just be asking for trouble.
3. Wrap every lazy load property access in a transaction. Works but is bloaty and error prone. (i.e. if I forget to wrap an accessor then it will still work fine. Only using NHProf will tell me the problem)
4. Always load all the data for the properties I might need when I load the initial object. Again, this is error prone, both with loading data that you don't need (because the later call to access it has been removed at some point) or with not loading data that you do

So is there a better way?
Any help/thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I has had the same feelings when I first encountered this warning in NHProf. In web applications I think the most popular way is to have opened transaction (and unit of work) for the whole duration of request. For desktop applications managing transactions (as well as sessions) may be painful. You can use automatic transaction management frameworks (e.g. Castle) and declare with attributes service methods that should be run within transaction. With this approach you can wrap multiple operations into single transaction denending on your requirements. Also, I was using session-per-view approach with one opened session per view and manual transaction management (in this case I just ignored profiler warnings about implicit transactions).
As for your considerations: I strongly don't recommend 2) and 3). 1) and 4) are points to consider. But the general advice is: think, then try different approaches and find a solution that suits better for your particular situation.